# Add ID to output only for first option

Tags: php, functions

I am looking to add an extra ID to the output: `<div id="NEWID" class="kalec">` if the shortcode is called with the value `no=0` i.e. `[photo no="0"]`

I need to use an IF statement within my output but can't figure out the correct syntax.

```
  function photo_shortcode($atts){
       extract(shortcode_atts(array(
          'no' => 1,
       ), $atts));

       $no     = ( $no       != ''     ) ? $no : 1;
       $images = get_field('fl_gallery');
       $image  = $images[$no];

    if ($image) {
       $credit = get_field('fl_credit', $image['id']);
       return '<div class="kalim"><img title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" src="' . $image['url'] . '" />' . (!empty($credit) ? '<div [INSERT IF STATEMENT] class="kalec"><div class="kalca">' . $image['caption'] . '</div><div class="kalcr">Credit:' . $credit . '</div></div>': '' ) . '</div>' ;
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `if` check, use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) so that any boolean-ish value can be passed in the shortcode attribute; e.g., yes, no, on, off, true, false, 0, 1.

```
$no = filter_var( $no, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );
```

Now, `$no` is either `true` or `false` (boolean).

---

Sorry, I see `$no` is actually a number. My mistake.

```
if ( $no === '0' ) {
    $no = 0;
} else {
    $no = (int) $no;
}
```

Uses [strict comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `===`

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your code lacks several check. I am trying cover some of those. For example.

1. `$no` is not being checked for numeric value
2. `$image[$no]` should be verified for existence before accessing.
3. Shortcode should return in all cases.
4. The string preparation should be improved.

Here is the code (1), (2) and (3) fixed.

```
function photo_shortcode($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'no' => 1,
    ), $atts));

    $no     = is_numeric($no) ? (int) $no : 1;
    $images = get_field('fl_gallery');

    if (isset($image[$no])) {
        $image  = $images[$no];
        $credit = get_field('fl_credit', $image['id']);

        ob_start();
        echo '<div class="kalim">';
        echo '<img title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" src="' . $image['url'] . '" />';

        if(!empty($credit) ) {

            $id = ($no == 0) ? 'id="NEWID"': '';

            echo '<div '.$id.' class="kalec"><div class="kalca">' . $image['caption'] . 
                '</div><div class="kalcr">Credit:' . $credit . '</div></div>';
        }

        echo '</div>' ;

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for these points but what about the actual question - if no=0 output should be modified as ...<div id="newid" class="kalec">...

Comment: @JoannaMikalai, check now, Improved the HTML area as well

Comment: hmm there is sth wrong with your code, as I don't get any output at all...

Comment: The problem is with  if (isset($image[$no]))

Comment: Also if id is not 0 - your code returns <div id class="kalec"> which is wrong html syntax

Comment: 1) What's wrong with ` if (isset($image[$no]))` 2) It should not be complicated to remove id="" from HTML. Updated code